# H1 tag CSS Issue - One Side Hanging low on WordPress website

Tags: css, wordpress

I am scratching my head as to what I've done here in my H1 Logo

The first image shows what is messed up and the second image shows how it should be on the same plane. I have to give link to image as I don't have enough reps yet. [Link to image](http://1drv.ms/1zmYCZX)

Here is the website, as as I am not sure what code would fix this: [afirewithin.me](http://afirewithin.me/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS:

```
#logo h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    float: left;
    margin: -7px 0px 0px;
    color: #262728;
    background: url('images/h1_border.png') no-repeat scroll right 25px transparent;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Change it to:

```
#logo h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px;
    color: #262728;
    background: url('images/h1_border.png') no-repeat scroll right 4px transparent;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Adjust the margins and the background 4px for exact spacing etc.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I played around with this for a few hours and just wasn't seeing the forest for the trees!

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin of 32px 0 0 on your h2

try installing firebug for debugging